# Can I make dijit/form/FilteringSelect less persnickety?

Tags: javascript, regex, dojo, fuzzy-search, dijit.form

I've been dissatisfied with the way [Dijit's FilteringSelect](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/selects/index.html#dijit-form-filteringselect) widget works for some time and have been tinkering using the Dojo 1.10 trying to improve it for my use case. Unfortunately it seems no combination of settings is quite right, largely because they don't work together.

- Setting `queryExpr: '*${0}*'` is nice, but it make auto-complete go loony.
- Setting `autoComplete: true` is nice as long as you want to type the whole text starting from the beginning until you find your match. Unfortunately if you want to start in the middle somewhere it becomes a pain in the butt. Sure you can set `searchDelay: N` to to something large enough to catch all your typing, but as soon as you let it return incremental results in the menu, BAM your ability to keep typing and maybe end up with a match somewhere else in the word goes out the window.

What I really want is something that completes much like a fuzzy-finder does in a shell or decent text editor (e.g. [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf)). Such finders skip over intermediate characters, basically splitting your input by character and adding implicit wild-cards between them. You keep typing until the first match is the one you want, then end the finder and let it replace the value.

I started messing with a way to implement this, but didn't get very far. I thought about hijacking [`_patternToRegExp()`](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/1.10/form/_SearchMixin.js#L77), but quickly discovered that my store (an instance of `dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore` with some JSON data) sets the _oldAPI flag and [that never gets executed](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/1.10/form/_SearchMixin.js#L261). I'm happy to update stores, but it isn't readily apparent to me that will make this easier. Hacking on my store, things spiraled out of control and I decided to take a less involved but more hackish approach.

If you turn off auto complete and set the options to do matching in the middle of words, you get a results list pretty close to what is needed. All that remains for the user to do is hit <kbd>Down</kbd> once after they type in enough input to get a match and before they <kbd>Tab</kbd> away. The question then becomes how to avoid requiring this manual intervention and become more forgiving.

```
define(["dijit/form/FilteringSelect"], function(FilteringSelect){
return declare("alerque.FuzzyFilter", [FilteringSelect], {
    autoComplete: false,
    highlightMatch: 'all',
    ignoreCase: true,
    queryExpr: '*${0}*',
    searchDelay: 0,

    _patternToRegExp: function(qs) {
        // If this ever actually got called, maybe we could
        // return qs split with wild cards between all characters
        return this.inherited(arguments);
    },

    onblur: function() {
        this._autoCompleteText(this.get('displayedValue'));
        // Pick first match from menu
        return this.inherited(arguments);
    }
})});
```

Hijacking the `onblur()` function seems to be the right place to make a widget that defaults to the first match if you tab or click away, but I can't figure out how to actually use the first match from the menu.

How should I proceed to get more robust fuzzy searching with auto-completion of the best match? I don't want a ComboBox, the value has to end up being one of the values in my JSON data set. At the same time I want input options to be much sloppier than typing the value from the beginning or having to manually select a match.

Comment: What version of Dojo are you using?  Is `dojo/store/Memory` an option for you instead of `dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore`?  It might give you more options/flexibility on the data filtering end...

Comment: @KenFranqueiro I've updated the question with that info, but I'm using Dojo 1.10 and I'm happy to use a different store if that will help fix this problem. I'm dynamically generating the JSON data out of a database, but that it's not very much data and I can munge it into whatever format works best if only the UI widget ends up more forgiving!

Comment: @KenFranqueiro Since replying before, I wanted access to this data from other widgets and was able to convert the store to `dstore/RequestMemory` with a `dstore/legacy/DstoreAdapter` to make it compatible with the `dijit/FilteringSelect`. Not sure if that makes _this_ problem any easier, but it's something.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do but that `_patternToRegExp` is just a simple wildcard replacement of `*?` that drops anchors around it. Its actually dangerous as it doesn't account for literal metacharacters.

Answer (score 1):

maybe a workaround/solution for your onBlur :

set the queryExpr="*\${0}*" 
no delay and autocomplete off

On onkeyup of the filteringSelect you store the first value from the popup matches somewhere, then after onblur change the displayedValue/value of your filteringselect to the value from the first popup (if it was found & matches...)

**To get the first value from the popup:**

The first shown value can be found in a

element with id = *YOUR_FILTERING_SELECT_ID* + "_popup0"

so if your id = "mySearchData" then look for id "mySearchData_popup0"

if that element exists then store the innerHTML somewhere (hidden element or var ...)

**Adjust value from innerHTML to match value from store:**

From the value you get from the innerHTML, remove the span elements from it so it matches one of the values of your datastore

if your id from your filteringselect = "mySearchField" and if you are searching "123" and the first match in popup shows "test 123 number"
then the innerHTML value from the first popup will look like this

```
<li id="mySearchField_popup0" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" role="option">
test 
<span class="dijitComboBoxHighlightMatch">123</span>
number
</li>
```

So, little bit of String doodling (just remove the span tags out of the innerHTML value) and you will have a value that matches your first result after onblur.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion! The result is not perfect, but this does get me part of the way there. I [implemented this a little bit differently than you suggested](https://github.com/alerque/alerque.VerseSpinner/commit/6933d3737d005623cbcbb315adc50837afe206e4) but the basic idea is the same: catch the blur event and use the first item in the popup. I'm sure this code could be improved, but I was unable to find a less hacky way to `set('value');` than the `emit('click')` cludge going on here. The label value itself isn't actually the value in my store, so I can't just parse that.